# Access RNG Event Configuration options programatically

Tags: rng

I am creating a module that allows an admin type user to create multiple RNG events at one time.   I have that functionality working now, the next step is to configure the events programatically.

I need to be able to:

1. Accept new registrations
2. Set up the email notification (and enable it)
3. Set maximum users
4. Set the registration type

I'm having a hard time finding these values, and I'm unsure how to proceed. Do I need to set up SQL queries to handle these, or can I access these values in another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Accept new registrations, maximum users, registration type are regular fields attached to the event entity. Use the regular entity field API to set those. Email notifications would require a bit more digging.